# reCAPTCHA code won't show in IE6

Tags: php, internet-explorer-6, recaptcha

I'm using the [reCAPTCHA service from Google](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) but I have problem in IE6 where it doesn't show the code.

Is there something that I need to configure?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298239/ie6-dose-not-parse-the-loaded-javascript-file-recaptcha-hosted-by-google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done any customization to the look and feel of the Recaptcha? I just did the below and then on a failed submit the captcha form wouldn't display in IE6.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'white' }; </script>
```

Removing the theme change made it work again, currently looking into a fix to get it working with the theme, will update here if I find anything.

Comment: Hi Petet, Thank you for your comments. Its really help me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-JavaScript API?

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#Standard